# Visual Studio: adding image as resource vs. simply adding the file

Tags: wpf, image, visual-studio, resources

What is the difference between adding an existing image (.png) as a resource and simply adding the file to the solution? Which is to be preferred, in general and especially as a button content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A build action of 'Resource' embeds the image in your assembly so that it doesn't need to be shipped as a loose file with your application.  A build action of 'Content' adds the image to the manifest so the application knows about it and expects it to be present, but doesn't embed the image--you need to deploy the file separately, and the application will search for it at runtime.  Both resources and content can be referenced with relative and absolute `pack:` URIs.

A build action of 'None' does nothing.  If you include the file with your application, you won't be able to reference it with a `pack:` URI unless you use the absolute URI form with a `siteoforigin:,,,` authority.  It's best not to do this, especially since the behavior changes when your application is deployed with ClickOnce.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just for clarification: you talk about Add -> Existing Item and then setting the build action. How does that compare to adding via the resource editor on the Resource.resx?

Comment: WPF does not use `.resx` resource files (or the build action 'Embedded Resource').  That system was used by WinForms, but WPF uses a totally different resource management scheme.

Comment: Hm, but it is still there? In the Solution Explorer under "ProjectName"->Properties->Resource.resx next to Settings.settings

Comment: The file may be there.  You can still use `.resx` resources for localization and such in your C# code, but WPF will not search for resources in there.  WPF resources (build action "Resource") are embedded differently.